Lock door without using the lock or at least detect en
I will have some contracted workers in an apartment to work unattended.
The doors in the various rooms lock only from the inside and don't have a key but the locking mechanism is like a switch that locks when you are in the room. That goes for all rooms.
Is there some kind of contraption that can be used to either force lock the doors from the outside of the room or at least if entry occurs it can be detected and can not be hidden by the person entering the room? E.g some sort of "seal" to attach that if the person opens the door they can't seal it back and it will be visible that they went in the room?

Transparent tape on the door and door frame, but cameras in the rooms, would be better proof.

@crip659: Wouldn't they see the tape or detect something when opening?

If looking for it.  How often do you check a door for a small piece of tape on it?

@smith if using tape, don't put it between eye level and the handle on the handle side; that's where they'll naturally look. Up on the top near the hinge side will be much more subtle, or right down near the floor on the handle side.  Or slip something like a piece of folded paper into the top (or maybe the hinge side), in line with some feature of the door.  When you come back, open the door, watching to see that it falls from the right place - even if they notice it appear on the floor, realise what you did, and put it back, they still won't know where it came from

... but these methods only serve to inform you, not to provide proof or to keep them out in the first place.

Then there is the prank version of a Rube Goldberg contraption set up so that a bucket of water dumps on the person who opens the door. Which is a bit problematic because of the mess it makes, but is quite effective. Of course, if someone is just looking for the bathroom and opens the wrong door, that would be a bit of a problem as well.

Door knob lock-out device.  Clamps on the knob with a gap, and you can't turn the knob.  I mean, I'm sure they can be defeated by a determined intruder—I mean, what can't?—but for casual thief, they may suffice.


Isnt this device for round knobs only?

Yes.  If you need security for doors with not-round handles, you'll need to come up with another solution.  Or temporarily swap round knobs onto the doors you need to secure.

Most bed and bath door locks have a hole in the middle of the outside knob.

A key can be inserted in the hole to unlock the door.  The key is a simple stiff wire with a flat end, or like a long pin called a Privacy keys. (available online or at most hardware stores.)   It usually has to be inserted until it bottoms and then turned slowly until the flat finds a slot in the lock. Then another 1/4 turn will unlock the door.  Some only require the wire-key be inserted and a firm push will unlock the door.
This is so the parents can get in the room when children lock themselves in.  You could use the same method of pushing or turning the lock, closing the door to have it locked, then open with the privacy key when you get home.

So they take a simple nail, call it a privacy key, and charge ten times the cost?  No wonder I am not rich.

The powers that be know that if your young child is locked in the room and crying, you will pay 5x the cost for that key...lol

anybody can open that lock with a nail or a thin screwdriver or a toothpick

@jsotola, but not everybody knows that.

@RMDman: No the door noobs are not like that. They are the traditional (non round) ones and no hole

@RMDman but I bet most contractors would, and would probably realise that you can lock them that way too.  Here in the UK it's even simpler - the outer part of a domestic privacy lock usually has a visible slot that will take a screwdriver, thin coin, or the back of some keys.  On the ones in my house I can get enough grip to turn them by hand

-1 All the locks of this type that I have seen (I have some similar ones in my house) are designed so that the act of closing the door will unlock them. That prevents someone from accidentally locking themselves out, but also prevents using it as even a minimal preventive measure.

Every bed and bath door in my house can be locked by turning the center tab and closing the door.  Yes , possibly causing an accidental lock out.  That is the reason for the cheep "privacy key" .  Perhaps the auto unlock is something new, ( My house is circa 1987)
